# Writing a loop to conditionally display a custom post type, checking for ACF fields and Event Calendar Pro events

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm making a site for a cookery school, and I need help with writing a loop. The loop will display the types of classes they provide, as long as each of those types of classes has upcoming events. Any help would be really appreciated, as everything I've tried so far has failed.

I'm using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin as well as the Events Calendar Pro plugin from Modern Tribe. I'll refer to the post type created by the Events Calendar Pro plugin as 'events' from now on.

I have a custom post type called 'class-type' which I've set up in my functions.php file. Each post of this type is a type of class that the cookery school offers, for instance DIY Pizza Club, Street Food Mastercless etc. The single post view will have images and details of that class, with a loop of upcoming events of that category, with the categories being the class name.

The 'class-type' post type has an ACF field called 'class_age', which is a select menu with the options 'For Adults' or 'For Kids & Teens'. It also has an ACF field called 'class_to_display', which is a taxonomy field showing categories from the Tribe Events posts.

The cookery school has two locations, and each event has it's location set to one of these.

The loop I need help with will have 4 variations on four different pages, and once I have the loop working I can make these variations myself. The variations will be:

- Bristol, For Adults
- Bristol, For Kids & Teens
- Cardiff, For Adults
- Cardiff, For Kids & Teens

So using the first variation as an example, the loop will need to do the following:

1. Get posts of type 'class-type'.
2. For each post, check that the post's ACF field 'class_age' is 'For Adults'.
3. Get the value in the post's ACF field 'class_to_display' and store it in a variable.
4. Check for posts of type 'events' with that variable as their category and with 'Bristol' as their location.
5. If events exist that meet those criteria, display the 'class-type' post's ACF fields of 'class_main_image', 'class_title', and 'class_short_description'.

I hope that's clear, and feel free to ask if you have any questions. Again, I really appreciate anyone taking the time to help!

Here's what I have so far which goes up to step 3 above, and is tested and working (the echo in p tags is just to check it works):

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'class-type',
    'meta_key'      => 'class_age',
    'meta_value'    => 'For Adults'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $the_query->have_posts() ):

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

        $cookery_class = get_field('class_to_display'); ?>

        <p><?php echo $cookery_class->name; ?></p>

    <?php endwhile;

endif;

wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Well structured question. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'll edit the question adding what I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Much to my surprise, I nailed it! Here's the code that works, hope it helps somebody.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'class-type',
    'meta_key'      => 'class_age',
    'meta_value'    => 'For Adults'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $the_query->have_posts() ):

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

        $cookery_class      = get_field('class_to_display');
        $cookery_class      = (str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($cookery_class->name)));
        $check_has_events   = tribe_get_events( array(
                'tribe_events_cat'  => $cookery_class,
                'venue'             => 59
            )
        );

        if($check_has_events) {

            $image = get_field('class_main_image'); ?>

            <div class="cookery-class">

                <?php if( !empty($image) ): ?>

                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

                <?php endif; ?>

                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

                <p><?php the_field('class_short_description'); ?></p>

            </div>

        <?php }

    endwhile;

endif;

wp_reset_query(); ?>
```